# Best way to get reference to controle win Extjs Controller

Tags: extjs4

I´m looking a good way to reference two controls in my window, using extjs refs system.

Here is my view code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Filter',{
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.myfilter',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'combobox'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Search',
                action: 'search'
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

});

I want to access the combobox and the textfield. My first attempt wat to do this:

```
refs: [
    {
        ref: 'combo',
        selector: 'myfilter combobox:first'
    },
    {
        ref: 'filter',
        selector: 'myfilter textfield:first'
    }
],
```

But the "filter" get the combobox too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the itemId property to your items:

```
items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            itemId: 'myCombobox'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            itemId: 'myTextfield'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Search',
            action: 'search'
        }

    ]
```

Then you can reference them like this:

```
refs: [
{
    ref: 'combo',
    selector: 'myfilter #myCombobox'
},
{
    ref: 'filter',
    selector: 'myfilter #myTextfield'
}
],
```

Your 'filter' reference was getting the combobox as well because the combobox class inherits from textfield, this is why it is usually better to use the itemId property.

Comment: What happens if I open another windows with a control with the same id ?

Comment: Then the selector would return components from both windows. If you plan to have multiple window instances at once, I would suggest keeping a reference to each one, then you can do something like window1.down('#myTextfield') on the instance you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
Ext.define('App.view.Filter',{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.myfilter',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        itemId: 'myCombobox'
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        itemId: 'myTextfield'
    }]
});

window1 = Ext.create('App.view.Filter').show();
window2 = Ext.create('App.view.Filter').show();

window1.down('#myCombobox');
```

This way you can just grab the components from the specific window you are interested in.
Check out the docs for [down](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-down) for more info.

Comment: No, I get this error: "Uncaught Ext.AbstractManager.register(): Registering duplicate id "combobox" with this manager"

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't happen as long as you are using "itemId" and not "id". The following is from the Ext JS 4 docs "Since itemId's are an index to the container's internal MixedCollection, the itemId is scoped locally to the container -- avoiding potential conflicts with Ext.ComponentManager which requires a unique id."
Either way, I'm glad my other answer does what you are looking for!